# Twilio - how to handle inbound sms

Tags: python, django, twilio, sms

I just made an account on twilio and I was able to configure things so that I can send sms through a django app I wrote.

However, now I am trying to understand what hapens to inbounds sms.

**Edit**
I configured an URL on my django app to perform some actions and then I configured twilio to hit that URL when an inbound message arrives.

However, the process failed and I got this response from Twilio (see below). It seems something security related, right?

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">
                <title>403 Forbidden</title>
                <style type="text/css">
    html * { padding:0; margin:0; }
    body * { padding:10px 20px; }
    body * * { padding:0; }
    body { font:small sans-serif; background:#eee; color:#000; }
    body>div { border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; }
    h1 { font-weight:normal; margin-bottom:.4em; }
    h1 span { font-size:60%; color:#666; font-weight:normal; }
    #info { background:#f6f6f6; }
    #info ul { margin: 0.5em 4em; }
    #info p, #summary p { padding-top:10px; }
    #summary { background: #ffc; }
    #explanation { background:#eee; border-bottom: 0px none; }
  </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="summary">
                    <h1>Forbidden 
                        <span>(403)</span>
                    </h1>
                    <p>CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.</p>
                    <p>You are seeing this message because this HTTPS site requires a â€œReferer headerâ€ to be sent by your Web browser, but none was sent. This header is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.</p>
                    <p>If you have configured your browser to disable â€œRefererâ€ headers, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for HTTPS connections, or for â€œsame-originâ€ requests.</p>
                    <p>If you are using the &lt;meta name=&quot;referrer&quot; content=&quot;no-referrer&quot;&gt; tag or including the â€œReferrer-Policy: no-referrerâ€ header, please remove them. The CSRF protection requires the â€œRefererâ€ header to do strict referer checking. If youâ€™re concerned about privacy, use alternatives like &lt;a rel=&quot;noreferrer&quot; â€¦&gt; for links to third-party sites.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="info">
                    <h2>Help</h2>
                    <p>Reason given for failure:</p>
                    <pre>
    Referer checking failed - no Referer.
    </pre>
                    <p>In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when
  
                        <a
  href="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/">Django's
  CSRF mechanism</a> has not been used correctly.  For POST forms, you need to
  ensure:
                    </p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Your browser is accepting cookies.</li>
                        <li>The view function passes a 
                            <code>request</code> to the template's 
                            <a
    href="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.base.Template.render">
                                <code>render</code>
                            </a>
    method.
                        </li>
                        <li>In the template, there is a 
                            <code>{% csrf_token
    %}</code> template tag inside each POST form that
    targets an internal URL.
                        </li>
                        <li>If you are not using 
                            <code>CsrfViewMiddleware</code>, then you must use
    
                            <code>csrf_protect</code> on any views that use the 
                            <code>csrf_token</code>
    template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.
                        </li>
                        <li>The form has a valid CSRF token. After logging in in another browser
    tab or hitting the back button after a login, you may need to reload the
    page with the form, because the token is rotated after a login.</li>
                    </ul>
                    <p>You're seeing the help section of this page because you have 
                        <code>DEBUG =
  True</code> in your Django settings file. Change that to 
                        <code>False</code>,
  and only the initial error message will be displayed.  
                    </p>
                    <p>You can customize this page using the CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW setting.</p>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>```
````

Comment: Solved through this https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/tutorials/how-to-secure-your-django-project-by-validating-incoming-twilio-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to receive inbound text messages you need to create a webhook, that allows you to run your code when an sms is received (you can respond or do something else). Otherwise the messages will be lost. Read [this for details](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply-python) and [this for a sample code in Django](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/10/how-to-receive-and-respond-to-text-messages-in-python-with-django-and-twilio.html).

Comment: Thanks! I was actually reading that but I didn't fully understand how that works. Basically Twilio does and HTTP request to a URL that I configured on my django app...and then? Will the reply be in the request?

Comment: @giaggi When someone sends a text message to the number that you own, Twilio sends a HTTP request at the specified URL. Your Django view receives a request containing the inbound message and must return a response containing the message that the sender user will receive (Twilio provides `MessagingResponse` class that allows you to return a message). So you must write a view that returns the body of the sms that the sender of the inbound message will receive. The first snippet shows how to do that:  [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply-python)

Comment: Ok, I actually did that. I created a URL path on my django app and then configured that path as the url for twilio to hit with an https post. However, the process failed and I got this error (see edit  on the question). Any idea?

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: Solved through this https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/tutorials/how-to-secure-your-django-project-by-validating-incoming-twilio-requests

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue going through this tutorial on twilio. I was missing the validator so Django was not allowing the request to come in.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/tutorials/how-to-secure-your-django-project-by-validating-incoming-twilio-requests